# Update DataGridView after Child Form Closed

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, datagridview

I know lot of similar questions are out there. But, I'm really new to C# so, cannot figure out how to solve this.

I have a `DataGridView` on main form and I have a dialog box to add new record. So, what I want is to reload/refresh the `DataGridView` on main form when the dialog box closes. (Press **Save** button on dialog box).

So, I have a public method on the main form like this, which I load data using this method:

```
public void UpdateProductsList()
{
  String query = "SELECT * FROM product";
  con = new SqlConnection(conString);
  con.Open();
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);    
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  sda.Fill(dt);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
}
```

I use this code to open the child form:

```
private void AddProductButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add_product obj = new Add_product();
    obj.ShowDialog();
}
```

Now I call this method on the Child form when the Save button is clicked.

```
private void SaveProductButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveProduct();
    Products products = new Products();
    products.UpdateProductsList();
}
```

However, this is not working when the Save button is clicked. Strange thing is, when I add this method to a local button on the main form, it works without a problem.

I also added a `MessageBox` to `UpdateProductsList` and I'm sure it was called, also the data was inserted in database, but the `DataGridView` doesn't show new record.

So, where I've gone wrong ?

Comment: Why do you want to create new Form "Products products = new Products();" ? Just send the reference of existing main form to dialog box.

Comment: Can you just show me the way of doing it ? I'm kinda new to this OOP and C#

Comment: When you show the child form using `ShowDialog` yo don't need to call `UpdateProductList` from child form, instead you can check the result of `ShowDialog` and if it was `DialogResult.OK`, call the method. Also in your child form, in your save button, set `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`.

Comment: Currently your problem is in code of your save button, you have created a new instance of your list form and called its `UpdateProductsList` method. It doesn't have any impact on the open instance of your list form which you can see. It's a different isntace.

Comment: As a side note, `Add_product` and `Products` are not suitable names for forms. When you look at these names they are like method names,  `ProductAddForm` and `ProductListForm` are better options.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Got it! :) Thanks! and thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you show the child form using `ShowDialog` yo don't need to call `LoadData` from child form, instead you can check the result of `ShowDialog` and if it was `DialogResult.OK`, call the method.

Also in your child form, in your save button after saving data, set `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`.

**Show Child Form**

```
using (var f = new ChildForm())
{
    if(f.ShowDialog()== System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        this.LoadData(); /*Load data in list form*/
}
```

**Save Button in Child Form**

```
this.SaveData(); /*Save Data in child form */
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```

**Note**

- When [`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog is closed.
- If you show a form using `ShowDialog`, setting [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `Form` closes the form.
- You can set `DialogResult` to `OK` in your save button and set it to `Cancel` in your cancel button.
- Currently your problem is in code of your save button, you have created a new instance of your list form and called its `UpdateProductsList` method. It doesn't have any impact on the open instance of your list form which you can see. It's a different isntace.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem. And thanks for the side notes as well!. Fixed lots of confusions. :)

Comment: Can't thank you enough dude. Your suggestion solved my problem too

Comment: @CavidHummatov Glad to hear that it helped!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a sample, how you call the public method in main form from child form:

```
public class Products : Form
{
    public void UpdateProductList()
    {
        // do something here
    }

    private void buttonOpenChildFormClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var addProduct = new Add_product(this)) //send this reference of MainForm to ChildForm
        {
            addProduct.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

public class Add_product : Form
{
    private readonly Products _products;

    public Add_product(Products products) //send reference of MainForm to ChildForm
    {
        _products = products;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _products.UpdateProductList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this but it says `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: where ? which line ? In your case, you must add "this" to this line : "Add_product obj = new Add_product(this);"

Comment: Whay return empty form ?