# How to update datagridview in other form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, datagridview

I have C# winforms app and also i have two forms `Groups` and `GroupAdd`. I want to refresh/update datagridview inside `Groups` form after i insert data in form `GroupsAdd`.

I google and i found to many examples but that examples is only for one form.

Here is my code:

**Groups form:**

```
public partial class Groups : Form
{
   private void GrupeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM grups";

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(table);

                    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
                    bSource.DataSource = table;

                    groupDataGridView.DataSource = bSource;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GroupAdd form:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace TrgoManager
{
    public partial class GroupAdd : Form
    {
        public GroupAdd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static DialogResult Open()
        {
            GroupAdd self = new GroupAdd();

            DialogResult dialog = self.ShowDialog();

            return dialog;
        }

        private void otkaziBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void saveBtm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string query = "INSERT INTO grupe (naziv, opis) VALUES(@naziv, @opis)";

                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@naziv", nazivGrupeTextBox.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@opis", opisGrupeBox.Text);

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MessageBox.Show("Uspesno ste kreirali novu grupu. Kliknite OK da biste zatvorili prozor", "Obavestenje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                            this.Close();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Doslo je do greske prilikom kreiranje nove grupe. Greska = " + ex.Message);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show `GroupsAdd` using `ShowDialog`. Insert data in `GroupsAdd` and close the dialog. After closing the dialog, reload data in `Groups` form.

Comment: check update `GroupAdd` i paste all code

Comment: [Update DataGridView after Child Form Closed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38680825/3110834)

Comment: In your save button close form this way: `this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;` Also cut the codes which you currently have in `GrupeForm_Load` and put them in a method like `LoadData()` and call it in `GrupeForm_Load`. Also you should have a button to open your `GroupsAdd` and check if its result is `DialogResult.OK` then call `LoadData();`.

Comment: By the way, based on your new question, I should say you don't need to pass an instance of the list form to your add form. Just follow what I said in comments or take a look at linked post. You will find it useful.

Comment: Its sloved. Thanks for link

Comment: It seems you are used to use linked post without voting for them. I can see multiple posts which you used without you vote for them. Yes, voting is not compulsory, but it's recommended. it motivates users to share more useful answers. Also prevents them from posting duplicate answers.